# AJAX script with json format data not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My complete script is as follows

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function () {
            $("#vote").click(function (e) {
                var poll_id = $('input[name=pollID]', '#myForm').val();
                var poll_option_id = $('input[name=voteOpt]:checked', '#myForm').val() ;
                //alert(poll_id + "AND" + poll_option_id);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/poll/index.php/form/poll",
                    data: {poll_id: poll_id, poll_option_id: poll_option_id},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }, error: function() {
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And I have the following inside poll function in form controller

```
public function poll() {
        $pollid = $this->input->post('pollID');
        $voteData = array(
            'poll_id' => $pollid,
            'poll_option_id' => $this->input->post('voteOpt')
        );
        $voteSubmit = $this->modal->vote($voteData);
        if($voteSubmit){ 
            echo 'Your Vote Has Been Submitted successfully.';
        }else{
            echo 'You Had Already Voted.';
        }

}
```

Now the thing is that, modal is executing perfectly on page load. But ajax is not working neither success part is executing nor error. Also on uncommenting the alert before ajax, correct values are alerted. I cannot figure the error.
Please help

Comment: Do you mean to be doing a POST request or should this be a GET request?

Comment: yes i want to do a post request

Comment: Ok, I also noticed you're calling a file on localhost - you sure there is no CORS issue occurring?

Comment: Did you json_encode your response to AJAX?

Comment: what do you return from poll function

Comment: @Lewk if that would have been the case then error must have been thrown

Comment: Shall I need to encode my response again if my data is already in json format @NeoZeo

Comment: Thats not the issue @hrishi if AJAX is being executed atleast something will be alerted but here nothing is alerted

Comment: can you show how your code response back to AJAX?

Comment: Is your ajax is going to poll function ? any error in console. otherwise try to print post data in function to check your ajax going in poll fucntion

Comment: check your network, and tell us what is the response from server for this call. 404, 405 or 500?

Comment: how to do that call

Comment: Can you try change this $voteSubmit = $this->modal->vote($voteData); to 
$voteSubmit = $this->modal->vote(json_encode($voteData));

Comment: `But ajax is not working neither success part is executing nor error` did you manually check your url ? try passing post data manually using postman app and see if its working

Comment: Also check what values you get in XHR tab of your browser console . @pokemon

Comment: Actually I can't understand why localhost is behaving differently with same code at different times, now there is no error in console

Comment: @pokemon , First open console and go to network tab and then  running you code/ reload your page.

Comment: can you give an example @Rajan

Comment: @NeoZeo nothing happens after encoding json

Comment: @WasifKhan where to run code in network tab

Comment: @pokemon just load your page which have your <script></script>

Comment: Now I am damn sure that my scripts are conflicting each other

Comment: On using `$.noConflict();`  before `$( document ).ready(function () {` error part of AJAX is executing

Comment: comment second script and try

Comment: Please help all

Comment: temporary comment jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js and try it is conflicting

Comment: @pokemon posted an illustration might be helpful for debugging

Comment: On doing so error function of AJAX is executed what to do @hrishi

Comment: where you posted @Rajan

Comment: @pokemon i have posted an answer below

Comment: ok. now try to print something in poll function. check if it prints in console.

Comment: may br url in ajax is wrong

Comment: @pokemon check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44968121/5188344

Comment: No its not printing

Comment: then check url in ajax is it correct path to function

Comment: On alerting error i.e., through `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` it alerts `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\n\r\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}`

Comment: url is correct @hrishi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see there are many javascript libraries included. Very sure some of them are conflicting.
Try this before $(document).ready():-

```
$.noConflict();
```

After looking at your form controller code, I can see you are just returning a text. So ajax dataType should be HTML and not json. dataType parameter is to define the type of return value.
I can only see this one wrong point in your code. Your console response status is also fine, which means it is the dataType which is wrong.

dataType = The data type expected of the server response.

```
dataType:'html'
```

Comment: Can you please find what is causing so

Comment: Okay, that means initial error resolved. Code execution moves ahead. Check console for errors.

Comment: Can you share your HTML here?

Comment: On alerting error i.e., through `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` it alerts `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\n\r\n","status":200,"stat‌​usText":"OK"}`

Comment: Yup you are correct, now poll_id and poll_option_id values are not being accessed in function poll when I tried to print their values using print_r

Comment: just use $_POST instead of $this->input->post to access values. If you are returning text then put dataType as html in ajax.

Answer (score 1):

**For Example.**

See you can check is you script is actually sending post values or not these way.

[image: Example]

In you console > Network Tab. You can view which post values are sent as POST.

Now I had code in PHP Codeigniter and for me following code worked fine.

```
$("#username").keyup(check_if_username_exists);

    function check_if_username_exists() {

    var username = $("#username").val();

    var sRet = false;

    $.ajax(
     {
        type:"post",
        async: false,
        url: "<?php echo site_url('distributor/tenant/check_username_exists'); ?>",
        data:{ username:username},

        success:function(response)
        {   

            var parent_fieldset = $("#username").parents('fieldset');
            $("#username").parent().addClass('has-error');

            if (response == "true") 
            {
                $('#span').html('<span style="color: #0fa7b5;">'+"Login Username"+"</span>");

                $("#username").removeClass('input-error');

                $("#username").parent().removeClass('has-error');

                console.log('Success! This Username is available');

                hideToastr();

                sRet = true;

            }
            else 
            {   
                show_error("Error","Oops! This Username is already taken");

                $("#username").addClass('input-error');

                $('#span').html('<span style="color:red;">Username already Exists!</span>');

                console.log('Oops! This Username is already taken');     

                sRet = false;
            }  


        }
      });

    console.log("End Of Username Exists " + sRet);
    return sRet;
}
```

Also there is third party application [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) which will help your debug your application. It allows you to sent post data with form values.

**Update**

Also I think you might have multiple JS files include issue or problem with the order they are placed. FYI I used only `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.min.js` and everything worked fine. So try removing

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

Now for your controller I don't see where you encode or decode your json data.
If Your are sending the values as JSON POST to your controller then you must decode it.

First Check is you are getting JSON data in your controller.
If its working fine, then try for second step.
**Step 1:**

```
public function poll() {
        $polldata = json_decode($_POST);

        echo $polldata;

}
```

**Step 2:**

```
public function poll() {


        $polldata = json_decode($_POST);

        echo $polldata;
        $pollid = $polldata->pollID;
        $voteData = array(
            'poll_id' => $pollid,
            'poll_option_id' => $polldata->pollID->voteOpt
        );
        $voteSubmit = $this->modal->vote($voteData);
        if($voteSubmit){ 
            echo 'Your Vote Has Been Submitted successfully.';
        }else{
            echo 'You Had Already Voted.';
        }

}
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Did similar thing and the following happenned

Comment: On alerting error i.e., through `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` it alerts `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\r\n\r\n","status":200,"stat‌​usText":"OK"}`

Comment: Where is your json encoding of string ??? I guess you are using PHP so where do you encode your json data ? Can you post your PHP Code where you encode your data

Comment: my php function poll is already in the question where data is being submitted

Comment: Yes i can see that but where is your json encoding and decoding  ?? I am posting an update to my answer

Comment: after changing dataType from json to html it did worked and success function is called but the values of poll_id and poll_option_id are not being accessed inside function poll

Comment: Yes that is the possible error! now I have updated my answer and try to debug step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Your pool  if should be like

```
   if($voteSubmit){ 
                echo json_encode(array('msg' =>'Your Vote Has Been Submitted successfully.'));
            }else{
                echo json_encode(array('msg' =>'You Had Already Voted.'));
            }
```

and ur ajax success should be like

```
 success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }, 
error: function() {
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

//change your Poll function

```
public function poll() {
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $pollid = $this->input->post('pollID');
    $voteData = array(
        'poll_id' => $pollid,
        'poll_option_id' => $this->input->post('voteOpt')
    );
    $voteSubmit =$this->modal->vote($voteData);
    if($voteSubmit){ 
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('msg' => 'Your Vote Has Been Submitted successfully.')));
    }else{
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('msg' => 'You Had Already Voted.')));
    }
}
```

And a small change in success callback of Ajax

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data.msg);
    //option to view data in console log
    console.log(data);
},
```